# Tabelview constraints get missed when Device rotating

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, rotation, autolayout

I have a tableview that contains n cells on it And I Have these constraints for my table view:

**Constraints**

[image]

but in ipad when I rotate the device my cells are floated left and get margins from right:

**Landscape Mode**

[image]

but in portrait its correct.

**Portrait Mode**

[image]

it seems just my cells are getting it wrong ( I can scroll in table view from white space)
any ideas to fix this?

**my storyboard:**

[image]

Comment: Check for your UITableViewCell constraint, is it true?

Comment: How have you setup constraints inside the cell?

Comment: @nynohu can't  add constraint for cell is off.

Comment: @Rikh no I cant in autolayout I can't set it seems to turn off

Comment: @nynohu there is a content view and it seems constraints can't added on to it

Comment: You need to add constraints to the content **inside** the cell.

Comment: @Rikh Alredeady I set for views that I can set constraint on it, the content view that it's child of tableview cell constraint adding it seems to off

Comment: I have tried and can't set content for prototype cell too. So you can refer to http://useyourloaf.com/blog/self-sizing-table-view-cells/. It contains example for referencing.

Comment: @M_STRM74 IS problem re-solved or still facing issues??

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy no :( I still when I rotate device uitableview constraint are messed up

Comment: Show me your storyboard of this this controller only.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy added

Comment: Click on `All` instead of `This Size Class`, what did you see?

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy yes when I rotate device cells floating left